# How to check what certificate is being used in the connection with PHP?

Tags: php, ssl

I have a web site written in PHP and I want to be sure that my visitors use my SSL certificate, I mean I want to be sure that there is no man in the middle. How I'll do it?

Edit: Any trick to send certificate name from POST or GET?

Edit: Or I'll send a hash to a user computer, the user computer will hash the cert name with a javascript, and compare both of them whether they mach or not. Not best solution but better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that: MitM attack is based on the fact that the person between server and valid client **already has** all the valid certificates. So for your server he behaves like any other valid client.

Comment: But if I visit Google and if it is used trusted CertIsrl which is being used by Mossad (MitM) at a cafe then no one will get any certificate error message (because everyone will see the blue line) and they catch my password. It means that every time I visit Gmail I have to click the cert to is see if it is Thawte Consulting or not.

Comment: @george: yes, but it is a client commitment if the certificate is issued by any trusted certification center. This has nothing to do with google's severs - it's only about your browser and Thawte

Comment: @george: how is it related to SO and programming?

Comment: Yes, it is not much related, sorry, but it is a security issue, I don't trust anything else anymore. I want to cross check everything.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there *is* a man in the middle, all information that "your visitor" provides (which you might somehow use to identify what certificate they are using) would actually be information that the *man in the middle* provides. That means you cannot trust it (which is a good rule of thumb really even when there is no MITM).

In other words, this is not possible.

Another way you could reach this conclusion is this: if this *were* somehow possible, "man in the middle" would not be a term we all know today.

Comment: So I cannot get the cert name that user uses, by non-standard methods?

Comment: @george: How could you possibly know *anything* about the certificate your user "sees" unless the user told you? And how could you trust *anything* the user tells you since he's the MITM?

Comment: @george: how would it help for you? Man in the middle is the same client for you. You cannot determine MitM attack from the server

Comment: @george: so? Man in the middle is a client for you in this scheme. You know nothing about real client in this case.

Comment: @george: MITM "forgets"? He goes to all the trouble of *hijacking the user's internet connection* and then *forgets*? Why not say the MITM forgets to attack you at all and leave it at that?

Comment: @Jon, simply, can I get the the cert name with Javascript?

Comment: @george: Both me and zerkms have spent a lot of time already telling you that **this is not technically possible**. Let's please end this discussion here.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jon and @zerkms have already said, it's the client's responsibility to check the server certificate.

One way you could make sure, as a server, that the client is using a connection that has presented your server certificate is to request client-certificate authentication. Indeed, during the handshake with a client certificate, the `CertificateVerify` TLS message contains the signature of a digest of all the handhsake messages that have been exchanged so far, including the server certificate. If the TLS handhsake succeeds, the client will have sent the correct signature, verifiable against its certificate.

Of course, from the server point of view, this only works if you trust the client certificate.

This wouldn't completely solve the problem, in particular because it's not advisable for a client to accept to authenticate using its certificate against a server it cannot verify (even if the private key wouldn't be leaked, the identity of the certificate would be sent to the rogue party).

Again, at the end of the day, it's still the user's responsibility to decide whether it trusts the identity of the server.